# IF statement isn't working as intended

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have two modules, with an if statement.

Here are the two code snippets.

```
int sum;
        int input;

        singleDigit(ref firstRandom, ref secondRandom);

        Console.Write("{0} + {1} = : ", firstRandom, secondRandom);
        input = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

        sum = firstRandom + secondRandom;

        if (firstRandom + secondRandom == sum)
        {
            checkanswergradeoneaddition();
        }

        else
        {
            checkanswergradeoneadditionFalse();
        }`
```

Here is the module the latter is referring too.  Please bear in mind, I have only been in my programming course since September 2nd.

```
       static void checkanswergradeoneadditionFalse()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int responseTwo = rnd.Next(0, 3);

            switch (responseTwo)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect, mush!");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("Wrong again, Einstein");
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Default");
                    break;
            }
    }
```

It's not working as intended.

Comment: define `isn't working as intended`.. how should it work? I can only see one if statement in the code samples you've provided. Where is the other?

Comment: (1) There is only _one_ `if` statement in the code you posted. (2) You didn't say _what_ your code does, what it is supposed to do, and why these differ.

Comment: Please Explain us What you want to Achieve and What is your Error?

Comment: @Rayne, welcome to SO. But you need to pose your question more effectively if you want positive responses and answers. There are thousands of people prepared to help, but only once you understand the rules of the game. Good luck!

Comment: I'm surprised at the downvotes - the question maybe lacking in places but considering OP is new to SO and programming it seems a bit harsh.

Comment: Along with what everyone else is saying about needing more detail, you can also determine if code is being reached or not by using breakpoints and debug stepping in Visual Studio: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2010-A-Beginn

Comment: Originally the else statement was an if statement, What I'm asking is, the first if statement is being reached because the sum of firstRandom + secondRandom is correct because i tested it, however, when i purposely input an incorrect answer, I want it to go to the checkanswergradeadditionFalse() module and that module will output a random case statement answer of the sum being incorrect. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: I'm glad they're teaching c# in schools these days.  It's a great language.  It feels very clean most of the time.

Comment: @RayneBlackham Hey, you didn't accept an answer!  You're supposed to add a green checkmark to some answer unless the problem was not figured out.  StackOverflow has kind of an amish culture where if you don't follow "society's" norms, you get "shunned".  Heh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I get what you're trying to say. Your firs if statement will always be true, because it does not compare any of the users input.

```
int sum;
        int input;

        singleDigit(ref firstRandom, ref secondRandom);

        Console.Write("{0} + {1} = : ", firstRandom, secondRandom);
        input = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

        sum = firstRandom + secondRandom;

        if (firstRandom + secondRandom == sum)
        {
            checkanswergradeoneaddition();
        }

        else
        {
            checkanswergradeoneadditionFalse();
        }`
```

Try changing it to:

```
int sum;
        int input;

        singleDigit(ref firstRandom, ref secondRandom);

        Console.Write("{0} + {1} = : ", firstRandom, secondRandom);
        input = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

        sum = firstRandom + secondRandom;

        // Changed the first 'if' statement to compare the users input with the sum.
        if (input == sum)
        {
            checkanswergradeoneaddition();
        }

        else
        {
            checkanswergradeoneadditionFalse();
        }`
```

Take note of the comment above the first if statement.

Comment: Thank you for giving me the comparison so I could see the problem clearly.

I will be sure to format and be clearer of my desired goals when it comes to code in the future, I'd like to thank everyone for the constructive criticism. I welcome any input whether it be positive or negative, as I'm sure it will make me a better programmer in the future.

Answer (score 4):

look at this:

```
    sum = firstRandom + secondRandom;

    if (firstRandom + secondRandom == sum)
    {
        checkanswergradeoneaddition();
    }
```

It makes no sense. if sum is assigned A+B then A+B will always == sum.  The "else" will never run.

maybe it's supposed to be

```
if(input==sum)
```

Comment: I think you're on to something here. The input that is read from console is never used, I have a feeling its supposed to be in the place of sum here.

Comment: Thank you for the responses that helped, I have since changed the code to resolve the problems using the suggested posted; it seems to be working (reaching) now.

I have only been studying for nearly two months, my tutor isn't exactly clear with his teaching methods, he also stated that a lot of research would have to be undertaken at home. I'm in college studying procedural programming, first year of course.

Comment: keep working at it.  Programming will help you be friends with our new robot overlords in a few years. Also, please mark this the answer if it helped (green checkmark).

Comment: @RayneBlackham good luck with your studies, StackOverflow will continue to be a great tool for you. Be sure to make your questions clear and well formatted, and you will get some great answers.

Comment: It turns out, that I have to implement data validation, however, I currently do not know the syntax to incorporate such a function, any advice would be hugely appreciated, whether its the code or an article to read that teaches me the code.